# Drop 'Where' and move the condition into the 'First' in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, sonarqube

I have a windows application which has some similar code as below.
As class named `Order`.

```
class Order{
 public string Orderid { get; set; }
 public string CustName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in another class in this application, object for Order class is created and value is assigned to it.

```
Order order = new Order();
order = JObject.Parse(some JSON data).ToObject<Order>();
```

Now I want to extract the `CustName` based on Orderid from `order`. For this I have used LINQ.

```
string custName = order.Where(s => s.Key == "o123").First().Value;
```

I'm using Sonarqube to check the code quality. When I run the SonarQube tool , it is showing that I need to refactor my code where I have used LINQ. This is the exact line it shows.

```
Drop 'Where' and move the condition into the 'First'.
```

I have searched for it a lot but couldn't understand what it is trying to say. Can anyone explain me how to refactor this line , so that it passes the SonarQube  expectations.
Any input is highly helpful.Thanks.

Comment: `order.First(s => s.Key == "o123")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are perfoming an operation in two steps when you could do that by using the `First` lambda expression

```
string custName = order.First(s => s.Key == "o123").Value;
```

---

Linq method `First` definition:

```
First<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
```

- First parameter is the IEnumerable you are using (Linq are extension methods)
- Second parameter allows you to set the filter declaring a `Func<TSource, Boolean>` as parameter, that you could define as `s => s.Key == "o123"`

Answer (score 4):

What it is telling you is that the `Where` is unnecessary, and the code can be expressed as this:

```
string custName = order.First(s => s.Key == "o123").Value;
```

The logic of the original code is this:

*"look through the list to find any matches, and take the first"*

Which is the same as the changed code:

*"take the first match in the list"*

Note though that this code will throw an exception if there is no match. If there's ever a possibility that there will not be a matching customer, use `FirstOrDefault` instead:

```
string custName;
var customer = order.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "o123");

if (customer != null) {
   custName = customer.Value;
}
else {
    // code to handle no match
}
```

Comment: if _null_ is sufficient as the result when there is no match, it can be shortened to `string custName = order.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Key == "o123")?.Value`